# Laravel 5.2 - Eloquent `with` ignores empty data list

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have 2 eloquent model like this-

**Advertisement** -

```
class Advertisement extends Model
{
    protected $table        =   'advertisements';           //Table Name

    protected $fillable     =   [
                                    'user_id',
                                    'category_id',
                                    'sub_category_id',
                                    'title',
                                    'price',
                                    'description',
                                    'address',
                                    'location_lat',
                                    'location_lon',
                                    'is_active'
                                ];

    public function AdvertisementImages()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\AdvertisementImage', 'advertisement_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

and **AdvertisementImage**-

```
class AdvertisementImage extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey   =   null;
    public $incrementing    =   false;
    public $timestamps      =   false; // disable all behaviour
    protected $table        =   'advertisement_images';         //Table Name

    protected $fillable     =   [
                                    'advertisement_id',
                                    'image_name'
                                ];
}
```

I want to fatch data of advertisement with it's images. So what I am doing is this-

```
Advertisement::withTrashed()
    ->with('AdvertisementImages')
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
    ->get();
```

And getting something like this-

[image]

It is very much OK for me. But my problem is if any advertisement does not have any image, then the add is not including. So, I can't get any result like this-

```
[
  {
    "id": 4,
    "user_id": 4,
    "title": "Anything",
    "price": 12,
    "description": "sd sdf sdf sdf 123",
    "address": "Baridhara, Dhaka, Dhaka Division, Bangladesh",
    "advertisement_images": [

    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "user_id": 4,
    "title": "Anything new",
    "price": 12,
    "description": "sd sdf sdf sdf 123",
    "address": "Boshudhara, Dhaka, Dhaka Division, Bangladesh",
    "advertisement_images": [
      {
        "image_name": "4a06cb3f00aab0545e6b6d.jpg"
      },
      {
        "image_name": "4a2a46b5bbc7fd4c2dc64c.jpg"
      },
      {
        "image_name": "4acababf2bea9aa42b3188.jpg"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "user_id": 4,
    "title": "new",
    "price": 12,
    "description": "sd sdf sdf sdf 123",
    "address": "Baridhara, Dhaka, Dhaka Division, Bangladesh",
    "advertisement_images": [

    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "user_id": 4,
    "title": "13",
    "price": 12,
    "description": "123",
    "advertisement_images": [
      {
        "image_name": "4a0c5735b4dafdda6e957f.jpg"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

> ID = 4 and id = 3, this kind of elements should be included

So, what I need to do to include those results also (include emptl lists in with in eloquent)?

Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: it is an empty collection already

Comment: Thats valid behavior. Actually when you try to use the values, better to use `isset` for php and `hasownproperty` in JS.

Comment: I know that it is a valid behavior, but my question was - "So, what I need to do to include those results also?"

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay

Comment: but what would you include there? Like you want to have one key pair inside the object?

Comment: `"advertisement_images": ["image_name" : ""]` Something like this?

Comment: no, an empty array, "advertisement_images": [ ], like this

Comment: I just need all data, including those who have no images

Comment: You need to show us exactly what you want, because what you're describing (as shown in the blue box) is what you already have. When there are no related images, the `advertisement_images` relation property will be an empty collection (or array, when converted to json).

Comment: Yes, question is updated to show exact JSON @patricus

Comment: with relation includes all the row from parent with child if it has or returns null array if not.
may b you had mistake somewhere please debug.

Comment: I have pasted all my codes here, can you please tell me what is I am doing wrong @Rits

Comment: here `$this->hasMany('App\AdvertisementImage', 'advertisement_id', 'id');`
`id` your local key of `AdvertisementImage` table and `advertisement_id` is your foreign from 'Advertisement' table,
Right??

Comment: Yes, you can find more from here- https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships @Rits